# Using cookies in Nuxt 3 APIs and Middlewares

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

Is there a way to use cookies on server side in Nuxt 3?
For example, I want to set cookie in API and then read its data in middleware:

```js
// ~/server/api/testApi.ts

export default defineEventHandler(event => {
    /* setCookie('myCookie', 'myValue'); */
});

// ~/middleware/testMw.ts

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
    /* getCookie('myCookie'); */ // ~~> myValue
});
```

I tried to set cookie with `useCookie` in API but it is `undefined` in middleware.
I also don't understand how to use `getCookie` in middleware because it needs the `event` object which is not present in middleware.

**Context**

I want to create a very simple auth system. In `/api/auth.post.ts` I create some kind of token which is saved in cookie. Then, in order to check, whether visitor is logged in I need to somehow retrieve this token back from cookie in `/middleware/logged.ts`.

I am open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define a plugin to initial values from cookies via `pinia`, before you use them in middlewares.

---

For example, there is a value: `theme` in cookie

```
// store/theme.ts

import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import Cookie from 'js-cookie'; // you can use any Cookie packages you want

export const useThemeStore = defineStore('theme', {
    state: () => ({
        _theme: {}
    }),
    getters: {
        theme: (state) => stats._theme
    },
    actions: {
        setTheme (value: 'light' | 'dark' | 'system') {
            // update the value in both cookie and memory
            this._theme = value;
            Cookie.set('theme', value);
        }
    }
});
```

define a plugin to boot the store

```
// plugin/initial.ts

import Cookie from 'js-cookie';
import { useThemeStore } from '~/stores/theme';

function cookieFromRequestHeaders (key: string) {
    const headers = useRequestHeaders(['cookie']);
    if ('cookie' in headers) {
        const cookie = headers.cookie?.split(';').find(
            c => c.trim().startsWith(`${key}=`)
        );
        if (cookie) {
            return cookie.split('=')[1];
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}

export default defineNuxtPlugin(async (nuxtApp) => {

    const theme = cookieFromRequestHeaders('theme') ?? Cookie.get('theme') ?? 'system';

    const themeStore = useThemeStore(nuxtApp.$pinia as Pinia);

    themeStore.setTheme(theme);
});
```

---

Now, you can use it in middlewares

```
import { useThemeStore } from '~/stores/theme';

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to) => {

    const themeStore = useThemeStore();

    if (themeStore.theme === 'dark') {
        return navigateTo('/dark-index');
    }
});
```

---

A js-version full example with auth is [here](https://github.com/DengSihan/laravel-nuxt3-web), which is SSR, feel free to star it :)

Comment: What is `useCookieStore` in plugin file? You mean `useThemeStore`? And I dont have `setAllow` method...

Comment: I replaced `useCookieStore` with my own store but in middleware using `useAuthStore` returns undefined.

Comment: @CMTV sorry for my carelessness, I've updated the answer

Comment: @CMTV for nuxt3 with auth in cookie and middlewares, here is [a full example](https://github.com/DengSihan/laravel-nuxt3-web) may help

Comment: Thank you I will look at your example! The store works in middleware though I can't get it to work in API. But I guess I can simply set token after an API request on client side just like in your example.

Comment: Thank you again after 3 hard days I finally managed to create custom auth system based on this answer and your example. Yeah, it is kind of ugly, but it works! :) I would suggest you to edit your answer and add a link to your auth example)

Comment: @CMTV Sure, I've updated the answer, feel free to star it :)